# Problems with PIL and py2exe

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, py2exe

I'm trying to use Py2exe to convert a .py file to an .exe file. My program uses several modules from PIL

This is what my .py file imports from PIL (snippet):

```
import Tkinter, re, random, struct
from PIL import ImageTk, Image, ImageDraw, ImageGrab
```

This is the code I use to convert my .py file to an .exe:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe


setup(windows=[{"script": r'C:\Python26\blur.py'}],



options={r"py2exe":{r"includes": r'Tkinter',
                    r"includes": r'random',
                    r"includes": r're',
                    r"includes": r'struct',
                    r"includes": r'PIL',
                    }})
```

Problems arise when I try to run my .exe. When I click on the .exe, the program fails to start.

I found this: 
http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/py2exeAndPIL

However, I'm uncertain of it's relevancy. Seeing as my program does not load any images of any file format, but instead creates one using the **Image.new()** method.

Snippet:

```
self.im = Image.new('RGB', (w, h), self.Hex )
```

This is in Windows 7, if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the problem is apparently due to PIL's internal initialisation routines rather than anything specific your application does, I suggest trying the workaround described at the link you found and seeing if it helps.

If that still doesn't work, I also suggest running your application from the command line rather than clicking it, to see if you get a helpful error message displayed.